# Sum of cost in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables, for example 1st has id, and name.
2nd has id, link to 1st table by id and COST.

```
CREATE TABLE FIRST_TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                         name VARCHAR (100));
CREATE TABLE SECOND_TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY,  FIRST_TABLE_ID INT NOT NULL, cost DECIMAL(10,2),
                  FOREIGN KEY (FIRST_TABLE_ID) REFERENCES  FIRST_TABLE (ID));


INSERT INTO FIRST_TABLE (NAME) VALUES
  ('ONE'),
  ('TWO'),
  ('THREE');

INSERT INTO SECOND_TABLE (ID, FIRST_TABLE_ID, COST) VALUES
  (1, 1, 500),
  (2, 2, 400),
  (3, 3, 150),
  (4, 1, 500),
  (5, 2, 400),
  (6, 3, 150);
```

How to get sum of elements COST (of 2nd table), which depends on NAME (of 1st table)?

What i tried to do:

```
select FIRST_TABLE.NAME, sum(SECOND_TABLE.COST) TOTAL_COST
from FIRST_TABLE
left join SECOND_TABLE on FIRST_TABLE_ID = SECOND_TABLE.ID
group by FIRST_TABLE.ID
```

The problem is:
I have only irregular sum of cost - 1050 for every NAME.
ONE - 1050
TWO - 1050
THREE - 1050

How to get genuine values for every NAME?

And how will it look like if i have three tables and for key in 1st i have to get sum of 2nd table and 3rd table?

Comment: Shouldn't you group by FIRST_TABLE.NAME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
from FIRST_TABLE
left join SECOND_TABLE on FIRST_TABLE_ID = SECOND_TABLE.ID
```

The join condition is actually equivalent to:

```
on SECOND_TABLE.FIRST_TABLE_ID = SECOND_TABLE.ID
```

Both operands of the equality relate to the same table. This is not what you want. Instead, use:

```
select FIRST_TABLE.NAME, sum(SECOND_TABLE.COST) TOTAL_COST
from FIRST_TABLE
left join SECOND_TABLE on SECOND_TABLE.FIRST_TABLE_ID = FIRST_TABLE.ID
group by FIRST_TABLE.ID
```

I would also recommend using table aliases to shorten the query and make it more readable:

```
select t1.NAME, sum(t2.COST) TOTAL_COST
from FIRST_TABLE t1
left join SECOND_TABLE t2 on t2.FIRST_TABLE_ID = t1.ID
group by t1.ID
```